# Oracle XSD - ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string

Tags: xml, oracle, xsd

I am getting the error ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string when executing schemaValidate() on an XMLType object.

This happens because of the following date: "2016-05-26T16:37:42Z" but when I remove the Z and leave it as "2016-05-26T16:37:42" it works correctly.

Why is this happening? I need the process to run with the zone value because I cannot change the incoming files, it is part of the requirements. Also, it runs correctly using SSIS, but I need it to run in Oracle PL/SQL.

Here is my code:

```
DECLARE
   v_schema_url   VARCHAR2 (200) := 'Test.xsd';
   v_blob         BLOB;
   v_clob         CLOB;
   v_xml          XMLTYPE;
   xml_file BFILE;
   xmlClob CLOB;

   src_offset number := 1 ;
   dest_offset number := 1 ;
   lang_ctx number := DBMS_LOB.DEFAULT_LANG_CTX;
   warning integer;
   res integer;
BEGIN
   dbms_xmlschema.deleteschema(v_schema_url); 
   DBMS_XMLSCHEMA.registerschema (schemaurl   => v_schema_url,
                                  schemadoc   => bfilename ('DIR_XSD','Test.xsd'),
                                  local       => TRUE);
   xml_file := BFILENAME('DIR_XSD', 'test.xml');
   DBMS_LOB.CREATETEMPORARY(xmlClob, true);
   DBMS_LOB.FILEOPEN(xml_file, DBMS_LOB.FILE_READONLY);
   DBMS_LOB.LOADCLOBFROMFILE(xmlClob, xml_file, DBMS_LOB.LOBMAXSIZE, src_offset,
                             dest_offset, DBMS_LOB.DEFAULT_CSID, lang_ctx, warning);

   v_xml := XMLType.createXML(xmldata=>xmlClob,schema=>v_schema_url);

   DBMS_LOB.FILECLOSEALL();
   DBMS_LOB.FREETEMPORARY(xmlClob);

   v_xml.schemaValidate();

   IF v_xml.isschemavalid (v_schema_url) = 1 THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('valid');
   ELSE
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('not valid');
   END IF;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by adding the following to the DateTime definition:

```
xdb:SQLType="TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE"
```

also needed to add the following to the top schema defition:

```
xmlns:xdb="http://xmlns.oracle.com/xdb"
```